# Chrome apps webview tag - how to inject CSS or JS in time?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm writing an application which should embed specific website into a `<webview>` and inject some CSS and JS code to adapt this website for viewing on certain touch-sensitive device.

The problem is that I can't find a way to inject my code when page is loaded, instead the code is injected AFTER the page is rendered and, as result, all modifications become visible.

While code injection perfectly works with chrome extensions and content script (by setting `run_at` attribute to `document_end` on manifest.json, this is not the case for webviews.

**This is my code:**

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "main.js" ]
    }
  },

  "permissions": [
    "webview"
  ]
}
```

**main.js**

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', { state: "normal" },
    function(win) {
      win.contentWindow.onload = function() {
        var wv = this.document.querySelector('webview');
        wv.addEventListener('contentload', function(e) {
          this.insertCSS({ code: "body { background: red !important; }" });
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<webview src="https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></webview>
```

The same on the Gist: https://gist.github.com/OnkelTem/ae6877d2d7b2bdfea5ae

If you try this app, you will see that only after the webview is loaded and fully rendered my CSS rule is applied and the page background becomes red. In this example I use **contentload** webview event, but I also tried all other webview events: **loadstart**, **loadstop**, **loadcommit** - with no any difference.

I tried also using webview.contentWindow, but this is object is EMPTY all the time, despite [documentation states](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#property-contentWindow) it should be used.

Any ideas? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, use the [`loadcommit` event](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-loadcommit) instead of the [`contentload` event](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-contentload).

Second, add `runAt: 'document_start'` to the [`webview.insertCSS`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-insertCSS) call (this also applies to [`webview.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-executeScript), if you ever want to use it). The implementation of `executeScript` is shared with the extension's executeScript implementation, but unfortunately the app documentation is incomplete. Take a look at [`chrome.tabs.insertCSS`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-insertCSS-details) until the app documentation is fixed.

Here is an example that works as desired:

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', { state: 'normal' },
    function(win) {
      win.contentWindow.onload = function() {
        var wv = this.document.querySelector('webview');
        // loadcommit instead of contentload:
        wv.addEventListener('loadcommit', function(e) {
          this.insertCSS({
            code: 'body { background: red !important; }',
            runAt: 'document_start'  // and added this
          });
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Note: Although the previous works, I recommend to put the script that manipulates the webview in index.html, because the resulting code is much neater.

```js
// main.js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', { state: 'normal' });
});
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<webview src="https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></webview>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

```js
// index.js
var wv = document.querySelector('webview');
wv.addEventListener('loadcommit', function() {
  wv.insertCSS({
    code: 'body { background: red !important; }',
    runAt: 'document_start'
  });
});
```